# Responsive card deck

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I found [this example](https://www.codeply.com/go/nIB6oSbv6q) of how to make a responsive card deck using alpha 6 but it doesn't seem to work in the current beta 2. Does anybody know how to get it working in beta 2?

What I need is a responsive card deck that looks like this.
[image]

The images can have varying sizes, I have no control over that. I would like the image height fixed to 100 px and the images to resize without distortion. The body height should scale to the body text and the row should take the height of the largest cell. So basically it should look like the image above but with cropped images.

Edit: This is the exact code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.steemjs.com/lib/latest/steem.min.js"></script>



  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="card-deck">
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">2 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-xs-down hidden-md-up"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">3 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">4 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-xs-down hidden-md-up"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-md-down hidden-xl-up"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">5 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-lg-down"><!-- wrap every 5 on xl--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">6 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-xs-down hidden-md-up"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x270" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">7 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">8 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-xs-down hidden-md-up"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-md-down hidden-xl-up"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x270" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 hidden-sm-down hidden-lg-up"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x270" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-block">
                      <h4 class="card-title">10 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Which looks like this in my Opera browser:
[image]

This is nothing like the example or what I described above.

Comment: What have you tried? Your question needs to include an example of the code you've written to try to solve the problem.

Comment: You can check what the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks) tells about card decks.

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't that obvious from the description? The example referenced but with beta 2. I find it useless to copy paste the code referenced. I first started in another direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350007/limit-image-title-and-story-height-in-cardview but that didn't give me the card view. So I ended up with this example that seems perfect but doesn't work with the beta release. I specifically ask how to get that code working. The rest are extra details of my goal.

Comment: @Klooven. Those examples are not responsive.

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. I added the exact code for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hidden-* and visible-* classes no longer exist in Bootstrap 4 Beta. Also replaced card-block with card-body. I think it will solve your problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.steemjs.com/lib/latest/steem.min.js"></script>



  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="card-deck">
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">1 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">2 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">3 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">4 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">5 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-xl-block"><!-- wrap every 5 on xl--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">6 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x270" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">7 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">8 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x270" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
              <div class="card mb-4">
                  <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x270" alt="Card image cap">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">10 Card title</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </body>
```