# Bootstrap card-columns: Safari weirdly displays cards' box-shadow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I set up Bootstrap 4 cards using card-columns:

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="card">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I applied box-shadows to these cards:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .card-columns {
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

div.card-columns {
    overflow: visible;
}

div.card {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

div.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

Here is how Firefox displays them:
[card-columns in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0d5Q.png)

And here is how Safari displays them:
[card-columns in Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuV0j.png)

When using card-deck instead of card-columns, Safari displays cards correctly.

Any idea where I should start looking?

Thanks!

Comment: hey @vicent, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I got tired and stopped looking. I've been using card-deck with breakpoints logic (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47410225/9568489).

Comment: thanks, I finally added an internal div with a small shadow within each card and it works